# Wifi router disappearing after disconnecting rom VPN In Android

Tags: networking, vpn

Every time I use a VPN and disconnect from it my Wi-Fi router disappears from the Wi-Fi network list. 
This happens on my Android Pie phone and tablet.

I can see all other routers but not the router I was using. After I do forget the Wi-Fi and manually enter SSID and password it doesn't bring up the router. It comes back after a long time on its own.

This is not a problem with my Wi-Fi router because I can connect to it in my Windows 10 laptop and Ipad

Please help.

Comment: Does it reappear after turning WiFi On/Off on the Android device?  The issue is definitely the mobile device, but if WiFi On/Off does not resolve, it would be more beneficial to seek help on the [XDA Developer Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) due to the fragmentation of Android caused by OEMs and carriers.

Comment: No it doesn't reappear after turning Wi-Fi on/off.